# How do I detect input from the left or right arrow-keys in C#?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm using the line of code `if (Input.GetKey("left"))`, but it obviously didn't register the input of the arrow key. How can I detect arrow keys like this?

My code is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float forwardForce = 2750f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 150f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.GetKey("left")
            {
                rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.GetKey("right"))
            {
                rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            }
        }

        if (rb.position.y < -1f)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not what you asked about, but wouldn't it be more robust to use built-in functionalities (axes) rather than ad-hoc reading keyboard state?

Answer (score 0):

The `left` is the correct name of the Left arrow key according to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html). But as advised in the comments, it's advised to use the axes of the [Input manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html) so that the user will be able to customize the input keys, or use the overload of `GetKey` taking `KeyCode` as argument for a more robust solution if you want to "manually" check for the individual keys.

It's often advised to handle input in the `Update` function (but not necessary depending on your Physics configuration)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This is a reference to the Rigidbody compenent called "rb"
    public Rigidbody rb;

    // This creates variables for the movement
    public float forwardForce = 2750f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 150f;
    private Vector3 force;

    void Update()
    {
        force.Set(0, 0, 0);

        if (rb.position.y < -1f)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
        else
        {    
            force.z = forwardForce;
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
                force.x = sidewaysForce;
            else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
                force.x = -sidewaysForce;

            force *= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        }
    }

    // We marked this as "fixed"update because we are using it to mess with Physics
    // In this case Unity likes FixedUpdate a lot better than Update
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, force.z);
        rb.AddForce(force.x, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}
```

Comment: GetKey does not use the Input Manager. You may be thinking of GetButton?

Comment: Oh you are right, I read the documentation too quickly. `GetKey will report the status of the named key. This might be used to confirm a key is used for auto fire. For the list of key identifiers see Input Manager.`